# Vue3 object render invalid，but vue2 success

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

A simple demo

HTML Template

```html
<div id="app">{{ temp.progress }}</div>
```

Instantiate object

```js
class Temp {
    constructor () {
        this.start()
    }
    progress = 0

    start () {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.progress += 1
        }, 1000)
    }
}

const temp = new Temp()
```

vue2 render success (page display 1,2,3,4,5.......)

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
        return { temp }
    },
})
```

but vue3 render invalid (page display always 0)

```js
Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return { temp }
    }
}).mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue 3 creates Proxy object rather than augmenting the original object in place. Conceptually you can think of it as (in vue3 code):

```
const dataObj = { temp };
const data = reactive(dataObj);
```

`dataObj` is your raw object and `data` is the proxy. **They are two different objects**. The important thing is that `data` is reactive, but `dataObj` is not. All the direct mutations on the dataObj cannot be observed, because the observing utilities are all in the stub methods of the proxy object.

What your Temp class is doing, effectively it is mutating the raw object - that is what `this` refers to.

If your component does not own its data, i.e. the data needs to be externalized and passed in, and will be managed (mutated) externally, you will need to create a reactive object and pass it into your component.